# Why do not we use radian unit sign well?

Tags: unit-of-measure

[image]

Mentioned the word)
Radian-unit-sign, rad, unit, radian, pure number, ratio, symbol, speed, distance, time

Comment: There are a several answers to your question to be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803955/why-radian-is-dimensionless?rq=1).

Comment: $\text {cm} \times \text {rad}=\text {cm}$ because $\text{rad}$ is a dimensionless  constant.

Comment: And, by the way, entering your question by pasting in an image is not a good way to use this site. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) for how to use markup language to format text, and see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to use mathjax to format mathematics.

Comment: Please write the question as text and not just embed everything in a huge image. This is no good for visually impaired users, search engines, etc. In fact you have been asked not to do this in previous questions, but you are still doing it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am voting to close as a duplicate of [Why radian is dimensionless?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803955/why-radian-is-dimensionless)

Comment: The best proof that the angular unit "radian" is not evident is that it has taken a long long time before it is widely accepted, and even a longer time before it is more used than degrees (it is only in the second half of the 20th century that engineers where trained to use radians as well as degrees). But the interest of radians is in particular in their use with fractions of $\pi$ : $\sin(0.7854)$  doesn't sound interesting, whereas $\sin(\pi/4)$ is.